# How to display the description page of the AppStore inside my iOs Application?

Tags: ios, facebook, mobile, app-store

I want to show from my application (iOS or Mobile Web Site if possible) the AppStore description page without opening the AppStore application, like facebook do. See images below for exemples:

[image: When we clic below a AppStore Description page in opened inside the facebook application]

==> Result

[image: AppStore Insite facebook Application]

Thank you for helping me

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a feature available in iOS 6. You should take a look at the [SKStoreProductViewController](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/StoreKit/Reference/SKITunesProductViewController_Ref/index.html) class available in StoreKit framework.

According to docs in order to display an app store link within your app you will require an iTunes Product Identifier. For further reference please refer to aforementioned documentation.

Comment: Thank you for this answer but i have another question : it is possible to do the same thing from a mobile web site ?

Comment: You could probably use a direct iTunes web site link (like this: https://itunes.apple.com/pl/app/itunes-12-days-of-christmas/id479672983?mt=8). However this will open App Store app on iPhone/iPad, meaning user will leave your website.

Comment: Alternatively, if you are seeking to present a banner on your website that there's an iOS app available for it too (like, say, Yelp does) you should probably take a look at the Apple's Smart Banners, which is described here: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/PromotingAppswithAppBanners/PromotingAppswithAppBanners.html